# Apache Olinge OData service: EdmSimpleTypeException

Tags: apache, odata, olingo

I am getting EdmSimpleTypeExceptions in some of my entities when i try to access them via OData. I am using Apache Olingo for doing that. The problem is that I can't implement any types other than integer and String. If I use a double I get the EdmSimpleTypeException, although double is an EdmSimpleType. I also tried all of the other types which are stated as an EdmSimpleType.

Is there any explanation why this happens? Any known bug in Olinge or someting like that?

Comment: I know OData not familiar with Olingo, maybe you can try the Olingo mailing list http://olingo.apache.org/support.html to get the answers for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

`EdmSimpleTypeException` is thrown in multiple cases, mostly for illegal type values which do not match with the `entityType` metadata.

Ex. In `entityType` a property is defined as `non nullable` and a null value is passed into it.

You can check documentation for EdmSimpleTypeExceptions [here](http://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/api/edm/EdmSimpleTypeException.html).

Here in your particular case what most likely is happening that you are setting `EdmSimpleType` as `Double` but the value you are trying to put against it is not one of the following types `Double, Float, BigDecimal, Byte, Short, Integer, Long` and Olingo is throwing an error while converting it.

You can check the complete list of mapping between the OData type and Java types [here](http://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata2/org/apache/olingo/odata2/api/edm/EdmSimpleType.html)